# How to get nearby courts from given lat long in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get basketball courts on basis of given lat long in eloquent ORM. I tried to get that but here I got this error.

`Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Api\RADIANS()`

is there any way to get nearby location using Eloquent if yes then how? please help me out I'm sharing me doings so far.

HomeCourt Controller

```
public function fetchHomeCourts(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'lat' => $request->lat,
            'long' => $request->long,
        ),
        array(
            'lat' => 'required',
            'long' => 'required',
        )
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->setMeta("422", Constant::MSG_422);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $homeCourt= HomeCourt::where(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('latitude'))*SIN(RADIANS($request->lat))+COS(RADIANS('latitude'))*COS(RADIANS($request->lat))*COS(RADIANS('longitude')-RADIANS($request->long)))*6380 < 10)->first();
    if(!$homeCourt) {
        $this->setMeta("200", "No courts found");
        $this->setData("homeCourts",$homeCourt);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $this->setMeta("200", "Home court list");
    $this->setData("homeCourts",$homeCourt);
    return response()->json($this->setResponse());

}
```

Comment: functions in PHP are case sensitive. There's no `ACOS` or `SIN` or `RADIANS`. There are however `acos` `sin` and `rad2deg` (or `deg2rad`)

Comment: yeah now I get that, so in place of radians should I use rad2deg or deg2rad ?

Comment: Longtitude and latitude are usually expressed in degrees so `deg2rad` but it depends what you have (it's not uncommon to get it in radians).

Comment: i have lat and long that I will get from user via Google API

Comment: also how should I query in laravel is it possible to use eloquent or I need to go for raw?

Comment: That's in degrees.

Comment: And you can use eloquent **but** you need to use `whereRaw("ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('latitude'))*SIN(RADIANS($request->lat))+COS(RADIANS('latitude'))*COS(RADIANS($request->lat))*COS(RADIANS('longitude')-RADIANS($request->long)))*6380 < 10")` instead of `where`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144339/discussion-between-bhavik-bamania-and-apokryfos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what basically happens:

The user will give you the coordinates they are interested in (via a magic procedure, most pages supply a map that the users click on but it's really what is best for your users).

This is what your code needs to read:

```
public function fetchHomeCourts(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'lat' => $request->lat,
            'long' => $request->long,
        ),
        array(
            'lat' => 'required',
            'long' => 'required',
        )
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->setMeta("422", Constant::MSG_422);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $homeCourt= HomeCourt::whereRaw("ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('latitude'))*SIN(RADIANS($request->lat))+COS(RADIANS('latitude'))*COS(RADIANS($request->lat))*COS(RADIANS('longitude')-RADIANS($request->long)))*6380 < 10")->first();
    if(!$homeCourt) {
        $this->setMeta("200", "No courts found");
        $this->setData("homeCourts",$homeCourt);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $this->setMeta("200", "Home court list");
    $this->setData("homeCourts",$homeCourt);
    return response()->json($this->setResponse());

}
```

The `whereRaw` bit will pass that whole formula to MySQL directly instead of having Laravel trying to figure out how to build it into a query (since it's not a standard format that Laravel can handle.

From what I understand that formula is basically the for the distance on a the curved surface of the earth ( 6380 is the radius of earth in km and the rest looks like he arc-distance of two points).

Assuming that all courts you are interested in are stored in your database (you can either have a manual list or update them using some sort of overnight process to get it from somewhere) you don't need to run an API query on every request.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done using `Google Map Places Web Service API`, this should help you get the functionality you're looking for.

A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

A Nearby Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

where output may be either of the following values:

```
json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

xml indicates output as XML
```

Nearby search example

**The following example is a search request for places of type 'restaurant' within a 500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia, containing the word 'cruise'**:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Comment: actually I'm working on an API so I'm getting lat long in request parameters so in that what should I do? I'm bit confused in this whole process.

Comment: Call google api with that lat long request parameters

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the above answer with no success, but thanks to @apokryfos answer i did this, so, this is my code, i put it in a raw DB query.

```
\DB::table("users")
     ->select("users.id", \DB::raw("6371 * acos(cos(radians(" . $this->lat . "))
     * cos(radians(users.latitude)) 
     * cos(radians(users.longitude) - radians(" . $this->lng . ")) 
     + sin(radians(" .$this->lat. ")) 
     * sin(radians(users.latitude))) AS distance"))
     ->having('distance', '<', $this->rad)
     ->first();
```