# How to show Nearby Places with Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating REST API with Laravel 5.6 (I have to say I'm new because I might have used the wrong terms. I'm sorry about that,I'm improving myself. I need to hear my faults :) )

I have one function for find nearby places in my controller

```php
     public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    if($request->has('party_category')){
       $parties = Parties::where('party_category', $request->party_category)->get();//your new query here
    }
    else if($request->has('lat') && $request->has('long')){
        $parties = Parties::whereRaw("ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('latitude'))*SIN(RADIANS($request->lat))+COS(RADIANS('latitude'))*COS(RADIANS($request->lat))*COS(RADIANS('longitude')-RADIANS($request->long)))*6380 < 10");
    }else {
        $parties = Parties::all();
    }
    return Fractal::includes('places')->collection($parties,new PartyTransformer);
 }
```

and I'm using this url for send current location but when I giving them , laravel showing to me all parties not nearby.I want to show nearby places

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/parties?lat=37.043237&long=27.392445

but when I sending my parameter to url it showing

```json
{"data":[]}
```

I can't show any nearby places

also in my database I'm keeping lat and long like this :

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('parties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('places_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('party_title');
        $table->string('party_category');
        $table->string('rating')->nullable();
        $table->date('party_date');
        $table->string("latitude")->nullable();
        $table->string("longitude")->nullable();
        $table->integer('fav_count')->nullable();
        $table->longText('image_path');
        $table->longText('party_desp');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

How can I show the nearby ones ?

Comment: have you tried your query in database tool like mysql?

Comment: What problems are you running into?

Comment: try the query in mysql or whatever db ure using and then tell us the results.

Comment: check this one quite good solution in my opinion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254641/sql-query-select-nearest-places-by-a-given-coordinates

Comment: @PatrickMoore json result is always showing {"data":[]} :/ .

Comment: @JamesRiady actually I couldn't run this query on php my admin I don't know exactly what should I wrote. I found this solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998810/how-to-get-nearby-courts-from-given-lat-long-in-laravel  it's kinda same but I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @flex_ json response is always {"data":[] } also I updated my question sorry about that I should wrote json result

Comment: @BaranKARABOGA although i'm not sure i think you are missing ->get() in the $parties = Parties::whereRaw(). try adding ->get(); so that it returns a collection

Comment: @flex_ ah yes your right I added but I have still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed , I hope it will help somebody

```
class PartiesController extends Controller
{
        public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
          if($request->has('lat') && $request->has('long')){
                $lat = $request->lat;
                $long = $request->long; 
            $parties=DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT *,111.045*DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(':lat'))*COS(RADIANS(`latitude`))*COS(RADIANS(`longitude`) - RADIANS(':long'))+SIN(RADIANS(':lat'))*SIN(RADIANS(`latitude`)))) AS distance_in_km FROM parties ORDER BY distance_in_km asc LIMIT 0,5"), array(
                'lat' => $lat,
                'long' => $long
              ));
            $hidacik = Parties::hydrate($parties);
            return Fractal::includes('places')->collection($hidacik,new PartyTransformer);
             }
           else {
                $parties = Parties::all();
            }
       return Fractal::includes('places')->collection($parties,new PartyTransformer);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `$parties = Parties::whereRaw("ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('latitude'))*SIN(RADIANS($request->lat))+COS(RADIANS('latitude'))*COS(RADIANS($request->lat))*COS(RADIANS('longitude')-RADIANS($request->long)))*6380 < 10");`
you are missing ->get(). you need to add get() in order to return a collection which you can then work with

```
 //this returns a collection now since we added get()  
 $parties = Parties::whereRaw("ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('latitude'))*SIN(RADIANS($request->lat))+COS(RADIANS('latitude'))*COS(RADIANS($request->lat))*COS(RADIANS('longitude')-RADIANS($request->long)))*6380 < 10")->get();
```

Comment: thank your help I added but I have still same result.

Comment: @BaranKARABOGA then this is most likely a problem with the query itself.. try to somehow run it in mysql and see if it returns anything